# Need to convert or format hhmmss to hh-mm-ss using powershell

Tags: powershell

Using some Invoke-sql command, I'm getting time in hhmmss format, which is not readable.
I just want to format it in hh-mm-ss.

```
PS C:\Users\AV> $time=81220
PS C:\Users\AV> $formattedtime = ([datetime]::parseexact($time, "hhmmss", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).ToString("hh-mm-ss")
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ $formattedtime = ([datetime]::parseexact($time, "hhmmss", [System.Glo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

PS C:\Users\AV> $formattedtime = ([datetime]::parseexact($time, "hmmss", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).ToString("hh-mm-ss")
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ $formattedtime = ([datetime]::parseexact($time, "hmmss", [System.Glob ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Below is what I tried:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBId4.png)

Comment: Your time is 81220 ? what does it represent?

Comment: Do you mean `081220` instead of `81220`?  The "hh" requires 2 digit hours.

Comment: `[timespan]::ParseExact($Time.ToString('D6'), 'hhmmss', $null).ToString('hh\-mm\-ss')`